# Foreign key constrain ON DELETE CASCADE still throws constraint error

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

for some of the records in the database, I could delete entries in table2 which were automatically deleted in table1. But for some cases, that didn't happen, even though they are identical (same tables, same foreign key reference, different values)

I get following error:

```
SQL Error [23503]: ERROR: update or delete on table "table2" violates foreign key constraint "table1_user_id_fk" on table "table1"
  Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "table1".
```

The code I used:

First to remove constraint

```
alter table table1
drop constraint table1;
```

Add `on delete cascade` constraint

```
alter table table1
add constraint table1_user_id_fk
foreign key (fk_id)
references table2 (id)
on delete cascade;
```

When I perform a deletion like this

```
delete from table2 where col1 = 'someval';
```

It throws the error stated above.

Right now I can't wrap my head around it, because for different vals of col1, it does delete the record in table1 automatically, and for some it throws a constraint problem

Comment: `column_fk` in the error message is not the same as table1_user_id_fk.

Comment: Yes it's just dummy names

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us. `on delete` cascade works as expected. See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0e6035b904a300f9f6cff5a4637666d8 Please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** `create table` statements for both tables including **all** foreign keys, and some sample `insert` and `delete` statements that lead to the error you are seeing.